# javascript absolute beginner = stuck on function returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

Just for exercise, I'm trying to print out this pattern:

[image]

Here's the code so far:

```js
  var even = "&nbsp;#";
  var odd = "#&nbsp;";
  var size = 4;
  var rowCount = 1;
  var lineLength = 1;
  function writeOdd(size){
   while(lineLength<=size){
    document.write(odd)
    if(lineLength === size){
    document.write("<br>")
    }
    lineLength++;
   }
  }
  function writeEven(size){
   while(lineLength<=size){
    document.write(even)
    if(lineLength === size){
    document.write("<br>")
    }
    lineLength++;
   }
  }  
   if(rowCount <= size && rowCount % 2 !== 0) {document.write(writeEven(size));}
      else if(rowCount <= size && rowCount % 2 === 0){document.write(writeOdd(size));}
  rowCount++;
```

I'm stuck - first line prints out ok, second gives "undefined" and that's it.

Comment: Depends on when you're calling the first function. If it is after the page has been parsed, `document.write` wipes out all the previous content. In all cases, use DOM manipulation methods instead of `document.write`.

Comment: Forget about document.write in 2k17 ;)

Comment: you're trying to document.write the return values of writeEven and writeOdd, which is undefined.

Comment: As a beginner, I think it's important to have good code style. Ie. `if` and `else` at the bottom shouldn't be indented like that, `document.write("<br>")` in the `if` blocks should be indented, `lineLength<=size` should have space, like this `lineLength <= size`. Good style makes it much easier to think about your own code, and makes it much easier for people to help you. See https://github.com/airbnb/javascript for a style guide.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in `document.write(writeEven(size))` and `document.write(writeOdd(size))`. `writeEven` and `writeOdd` don't explicitly return anything. When a function doesn't explicitly return anything, it will return `undefined` by default. So when those functions return, `undefined` gets passed in to `document.write`, and is written to the screen.

Note that `document.write(writeOdd(size))` gets evaluated from the inside out. First `writeOdd(size)` is executed. Then it returns. The return value basically takes its place, giving us `document.write(undefined)`. Then `document.write(undefined)` is executed, and prints "undefined" to the screen.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values for more information on return values.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions call document.write, so no need to use it when calling writeEven and writeOdd, also you're missing a while loop for incrementing rows, and lineLength should be initialzed in each function

```js
var even = "&nbsp;#";
  var odd = "#&nbsp;";
  var size = 4;
  var rowCount = 1;
  
  function writeOdd(size){
  var lineLength = 1;
   while(lineLength<=size){
    document.write(odd)
    if(lineLength === size){
    document.write("<br>")
    }
    lineLength++;
   }
  }
  function writeEven(size){
  var lineLength = 1;
   while(lineLength<=size){
    document.write(even)
    if(lineLength === size){
    document.write("<br>")
    }
    lineLength++;
   }
  }  
  while (rowCount <= 5) {
   if(rowCount <= size && rowCount % 2 !== 0) {writeEven(size);}
      else if(rowCount <= size && rowCount % 2 === 0){writeOdd(size);}
  rowCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function print() {
  let flag = true;
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      flag ? process.stdout.write('#') : process.stdout.write(' ');
      flag = !flag;
    }
    flag = !flag;
    process.stdout.write('\n');
  }
}
print();
```